# antd locale: change single value of a translation

Tags: localization, antd

I have switched antd to use German translation which was quite straightforward:

```
import de from 'antd/es/locale/de_DE';

<ConfigProvider locale={de}>
  <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```

Now I like to change a single value of this translation that I find inside `'antd/es/locale/de_DE.js'`

To be precise, I like to change

Upload.uploading: 'Hochladen...' to 'Hochladen' without the three dots.

It seems such an easy problem but I can't get my head around to figure it out.